# Looking for ways to encrypt password in text files on ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

I'm looking for a way to encrypt the database password that shows on the database.yml file on a ruby on rails application, any ideas how I could make this?
Something like this:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: dblib
  database: db name
  host: host
  port: xxxx
  username: teste
  password: encryptedpass
```

Comment: If your Rails application follows best practices and you don't have the file where it could be served as a static file, and the server is secure, then there is no need to encrypt it. At some point we have to trust the administration and security of the system, otherwise you drop into a rabbit hole trying to handle every possible issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Environment variables`

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: dblib
  database: db name
  host: host
  port: xxxx
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASS'] %>
```

There's a good gem [**`dotenv`**](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) if you need to manage lot of ENV variables

Comment: how? can you link me a toturial?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/Shopify/ejson to add encrypted secrets to your app. It uses a public/private key pair to allow you to encrypt your secrets such that only your deployment environment can read them.

After generating your keys, you would place your plain text string your `secrets.production.ejson` file, then run `ejson encrypt <path/to/secrets.production.ejson>`, which would encrypt any unencrypted values. You can then safely add the results to source control.

You can then load the ejson file and makes its contents available via `ENV`, and use `key: <%= ENV['...'] %>` in your YAML files to read the decrypted values.